# Chromium for Android: How to always keep fullscreen mode

Tags: android, chromium

I'm creating a fullscreen app, but Chromium's UI has an URL bar, I dont know how to hide it everytime.
I found this function to enter the fullscreen mode, but cannot keep it, it will be go to exit if navigating to a new URL

```
getFullscreenManager().setPersistentFullscreenMode(true);
```

Also have another issue: How to turn off the red border? Like this image: [image]. But only get issue with Chromium.

Project I used here: https://github.com/kuoruan/Chromium-Android

Answer (score 0):

Update the theme of your project which you mentioned in your manifest file

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

*Note:* the windowNoTitle is will be true and windowActionBar will be false

Comment: My issue is: Cannot hide the URL controlbar, Do you have Chrome installed? you can see the URL bar in the top of the app, I dont want it :D

Comment: did you use what I said. I didn't used chromium in android studio sorry